# Get Next Element that is Visible and Does Not Have Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm an experienced developer with not so much experience in jQuery.

I have a table row (`<tr>`) element and I'd like to use jQuery to get the next table row that **A)** is visible, and **B)** does not have the attribute `id='count-me-out'`.

I think I could do this in a loop (although I have some question about checking visibility regardless of what attributes are being used to control visibility). But what what I'd really like is to pass a selector argument to `$(myTr).next()` that would implement this filter.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
const lookingFor = $(this).nextAll('tr:visible').not('#count-me-out').first();
```

Or like:

```
const lookingFor = $(this).nextAll('tr:visible:not("#count-me-out"):first');
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know if there is any performance difference between the two?

Comment: `next` only selects the `next` sibling element, it it matches the selector, it won't work in this case. Use `nextAll` and `:first` selector.

Comment: @JonathanWood Yes, it would return an empty jQuery object

Comment: @JonathanWood Yes, `next` only selects the next sibling element.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like `nextAll()` is what I need.

Comment: [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) with a selector returns the next element ONLY if the selector matches. It does not search for a following element that matches the selector. This is what can be achieved with [`nextAll(':visible:first')`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll).

Answer (score 2):

You probably want:

```
$(el).next(':not(#count-me-out):visible')
```

**Edit:
This is not a valid answer. See comments.**

Comment: Looks like this might return nothing if the next item does not pass the filter?

Comment: @JonathanWood This will search next siblings until it finds a match. If it doesn't find any, then yes, it would return an empty set.

Comment: According to @undefined, it will return an empty set if just the next item doesn't match.

Comment: @JonathanWood No, my code is different than what roXon first posted (before he edited). In his case, he was first selecting the next visible element, then testing it against the `not` filter. This code test the element against both filters before selecting.

Comment: I'm confused then. The documentation for `next()` states "Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector." Doesn't this mean that if the next sibling does not match the selector, it returns nothing?

Comment: @JonathanWood count on `.next()` like on a dummy fella. next is only ONE sibling elemnet. `.next('div')` is an example of matching a NEXT SIBLING (only one) for the used selector (DIV). If your NEXT SIBLING is a `TR` than you'll get.... nothing :)

Comment: @Andre NO PLEASE removing answers is not always the best. Even if it's wrong we commented out the case that might be REALLY USEFUL for someone to understand in-depth.

Comment: It does, indeed, return an empty set