# Get Current or Next Sibling Element Matching Selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I recently posted the question [Get Next Element that is Visible and Does Not Have Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168598/get-next-element-that-is-visible-and-does-not-have-attribute), in which I asked how to get the next sibling that is both visible and does not have the attribute `id='count-me-out'`.

The upshot was the following syntax which appears to work great:

```
var trNext = $(tr).nextAll('tr:visible:not("#count-me-out"):first');
```

I now have a variation on this where I want to use the exact same filter except that I want to return the *current* element (`tr` in the example above) if it passes the filter. If it does not, then I want to proceed by looking at the next one. In other words, it would work exactly like the line above except starting with the current element rather than the next one.

I guess one approach is to use `prev()` to get the previous sibling and then use the line above to get the next matching one. Can anyone say if there's a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 var trNext;
 if ($(tr).is('tr:visible:not("#count-me-out")')){
     trNext = tr;
 }
 else{
     trNext = $(tr).nextAll('tr:visible:not("#count-me-out"):first');
 }
```

http://api.jquery.com/is/

Comment: So would that be `if ($(tr).is('tr:visible:not("#count-me-out")') trNext = tr; else trNext = $(tr).nextAll('tr:visible:not("#count-me-out"):first');`

Comment: @JonathanWood don't you just want to know if the current tr passed the condition?

Comment: No, if it does pass the filter, then the current row is the one I'm after; otherwise I want to search comparing the next ones. I'll update the question.

Comment: Thanks for the information about `is()`, although I'm starting to think it might be simpler and possibly more performant to use `trNext = $(tr).prev().nextAll('tr:visible:not("#count-me-out"):first');`.